# Saving NSData from CoreData Managed Object in a CloudKit Asset

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I have a small image stored as `NSData` in a CoreData Managed Object that I need to save in a `CloudKit` record as `CKAsset`.

I was hoping to simply cast the `NSData` from the managed object like this:

```
myCKRecord["document"] = myCDRecord.document as! CKAsset
```

Unfortunately, this cast does not work, so I have made a work-around by writing a file with the `NSData`, and using the file to initialise the `CKAsset`.

```
class myManagedObject: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var image: NSData?
    @NSManaged var name: String


func createCloudKitAsset(myCDRecord : myManagedObject) -> CKRecord

    let myCKRecordID = CKRecordID(recordName: myCDRecord.name)
    let myCKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "myCKType", recordID: myCKRecordID)

    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let localURL =  NSURL.fileURLWithPath(dirPaths.first + "/" + recordName)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    fileManager.createFileAtPath(localURL.path!, contents: myCDRecord.image, attributes: nil)

    myCKRecord["image"] = CKAsset(fileURL: localURL)
   ...
}
```

This works, but is untidy, and I still have the temporary file to be cleaned up after the CK record is saved.

Hopefully, someone can show me a better way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to store large documents in Core Data. The blob data type should only be used for small images such as thumbnails.

Instead, your Core Data entity should just point to the correct file, either via your own directory scheme, and/or via a URL attribute. You would then just have to create the `CKAsset` with the `fileURL` parameter from the Core Data entity. To access the data, you would use the `fileURL` of the `CKAsset`, which will be different.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mundi.  Just pointing to the file from the 'CoreData' object could actually be a little easier so I will look at doing that.  

However, I think the underlying question still stands.  If I did just have a small binary object, e.g. a thumbnail image) stored as 'NSData' in 'CoreData', is there a way to convert this data to 'CKAsset' directly?  Or would I still need to write a file so that I can initialise the 'CKAsset' with the 'fileURL?

Comment: I've edited the original post to give an example that reflects appropriate use of CoreData.

Comment: The answer is contained in my response: you **do** need to create a `CKAsset` using a file URL, that's the only way.